# Google Foobar: Bringing a Gun to a Guard Fight

Tags: java, algorithm

### My Situation

I've been working on this challenge on and off for about 9 days now, and I'm out of ideas. So far my solution passes 9 / 10 of the test cases. My optimized solution runs quickly enough, so the error is the actual solution, not that it runs out of time to compute. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm missing or if my algorithm doesn't actually solve the problem given. Also, I realize some bits of my code aren't perfect - I plan to fix everything up once I have a working solution.

### Problem

Uh-oh - you've been cornered by one of Commander Lambdas elite guards! Fortunately, you grabbed a beam weapon from an abandoned guardpost while you were running through the station, so you have a chance to fight your way out. But the beam weapon is potentially dangerous to you as well as to the elite guard: its beams reflect off walls, meaning you'll have to be very careful where you shoot to avoid bouncing a shot toward yourself!

Luckily, the beams can only travel a certain maximum distance before becoming too weak to cause damage. You also know that if a beam hits a corner, it will bounce back in exactly the same direction. And of course, if the beam hits either you or the guard, it will stop immediately (albeit painfully).

Write a function answer(dimensions, your_position, guard_position, distance) that gives an array of 2 integers of the width and height of the room, an array of 2 integers of your x and y coordinates in the room, an array of 2 integers of the guard's x and y coordinates in the room, and returns an integer of the number of distinct directions that you can fire to hit the elite guard, given the maximum distance that the beam can travel.

The room has integer dimensions [1 < x_dim <= 1000, 1 < y_dim <= 1000]. You and the elite guard are both positioned on the integer lattice at different distinct positions (x, y) inside the room such that [0 < x < x_dim, 0 < y < y_dim]. Finally, the maximum distance that the beam can travel before becoming harmless will be given as an integer 1 < distance <= 10000.

For example, if you and the elite guard were positioned in a room with dimensions [3, 2], you_position [1, 1], guard_position [2, 1], and a maximum shot distance of 4, you could shoot in seven different directions to hit the elite guard (given as vector bearings from your location): [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, -2], [3, 2], [3, -2], [-3, 2], and [-3, -2]. As specific examples, the shot at bearing [1, 0] is the straight line horizontal shot of distance 1, the shot at bearing [-3, -2] bounces off the left wall and then the bottom wall before hitting the elite guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(13), and the shot at bearing [1, 2] bounces off just the top wall before hitting the elite guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(5).

### My Unfinished Solution (Java)

```
public class Answer {  

public static int answer(int[] dimensions, int[] captain_position, int[] badguy_position, int distance) { 
    
    int parallelDimensionX = (2 * (distance / dimensions[0])) + 1;
    int parallelDimensionY = (2 * (distance / dimensions[1])) + 1;  
    int numDirections = 0;
    int distanceSquared = (int) Math.pow(distance, 2);      
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> directions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> sourceDirections = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>> sourceTracker = new ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        
        directions.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
        sourceDirections.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
        sourceTracker.add(new ArrayList<int[]>());
    }       
    
    ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>> mirroredPlanes = MirroredPlanes(badguy_position, dimensions, new int[]{parallelDimensionX, parallelDimensionY});
    ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>> mirroredSources = MirroredPlanes(captain_position, dimensions, new int[]{parallelDimensionX, parallelDimensionY});
    
    for(int i = 0; i < parallelDimensionX; i++) {
        
        for(int j = 0; j < parallelDimensionY; j++) {
            
            int[] sourcePoint = mirroredSources.get(j).get(i);
            
            if(sourcePoint[0] == captain_position[0] && sourcePoint[1] == captain_position[1]) {
                
                continue;
            }
            
            int[] vecA = new int[] {sourcePoint[0] - captain_position[0], sourcePoint[1] - captain_position[1]};
            
            double direction = Math.atan2(vecA[1], vecA[0]);
            int quadrant = 0;
            if(vecA[0] < 0) {
                
                quadrant++;
            }
            if(vecA[1] < 0) {
                
                quadrant += 2;
            }
            
            if(!sourceDirections.get(quadrant).contains(direction)) {
                
                sourceDirections.get(quadrant).add(direction);
                sourceTracker.get(quadrant).add(new int[]{j, i});
            } else {
                
                int sourceIndex = sourceDirections.get(quadrant).indexOf(direction);
                
                if((sourceTracker.get(quadrant).get(sourceIndex)[0] < j && j < parallelDimensionY / 2) || (sourceTracker.get(quadrant).get(sourceIndex)[0] > j && j > parallelDimensionY / 2)) {
                    
                    sourceTracker.get(quadrant).get(sourceIndex)[0] = j;
                }
                
                if((sourceTracker.get(quadrant).get(sourceIndex)[1] < i && i < parallelDimensionX / 2) || (sourceTracker.get(quadrant).get(sourceIndex)[1] > i && i > parallelDimensionX / 2)) {
                    
                    sourceTracker.get(quadrant).get(sourceIndex)[1] = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < parallelDimensionX; i++) {
        
        for(int j = 0; j < parallelDimensionY; j++) {
            
            int[] currPoint = mirroredPlanes.get(j).get(i);             
            
            if(captain_position[0] == badguy_position[0] && currPoint[0] == captain_position[0] && currPoint[1] != badguy_position[1]) {
                
                continue;
            }
            
            if(captain_position[1] == badguy_position[1] && currPoint[1] == captain_position[1] && currPoint[0] != badguy_position[0]) {
                
                continue;
            }
            
            if(Math.pow(currPoint[0] - captain_position[0], 2) + Math.pow(currPoint[1] - captain_position[1], 2) <= distanceSquared) {              
                
                int [] vecA = new int[] {currPoint[0] - captain_position[0], currPoint[1] - captain_position[1]};
                
                double direction = Math.atan2(vecA[1], vecA[0]);
                int quadrant = 0;
                if(vecA[0] < 0) {
                    
                    quadrant++;
                }
                if(vecA[1] < 0) {
                    
                    quadrant += 2;
                }
                
                
                if(directions.get(quadrant).contains(direction)) {
                    
                    continue;
                } else {
                    
                    directions.get(quadrant).add(direction);
                }       
                
                if(sourceDirections.get(quadrant).contains(direction)) {
                    
                    int index = sourceDirections.get(quadrant).indexOf(direction);
                    
                    int[] sourceIndex = sourceTracker.get(quadrant).get(index);
                    int[] sourcePoint = mirroredSources.get(sourceIndex[0]).get(sourceIndex[1]);
                        
                    if(Math.pow(sourcePoint[0], 2) + Math.pow(sourcePoint[1], 2) < Math.pow(currPoint[0], 2) + Math.pow(currPoint[1], 2)) {
                            
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                }
                
                numDirections++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return numDirections;
}

public static ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>> MirroredPlanes(int[] startingLocal, int[] planeDimensions, int[]mirrorDimensions) {
    
    ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>> mirroredPlanes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>>();
    
    //int[][int[][]] mirroredPlanes = new int[mirrorDimensions[0]][mirrorDimensions[1]];
    int middleX = mirrorDimensions[0] / 2;
    int middleY = mirrorDimensions[1] / 2;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < mirrorDimensions[1]; i++) {
        
        ArrayList<int[]> curXList = new ArrayList<int[]>(); 
        mirroredPlanes.add(curXList);
        
        for(int j = 0; j < mirrorDimensions[0]; j++) {
            
            int[] curY = new int[2]; 
            
            int[] tempLocal = new int[]{startingLocal[0], startingLocal[1]};
            
            int modX = j - middleX;
            int modY = i - middleY;
                        
            if(modX % 2 != 0) {
                
                tempLocal[0] = planeDimensions[0] - startingLocal[0];
            }
            
            curY[0] = tempLocal[0] + (modX * planeDimensions[0]);
            
            if(modY % 2 != 0) {
                
                tempLocal[1] = planeDimensions[1] - startingLocal[1];
            }
            
            curY[1] = tempLocal[1] + (modY * planeDimensions[1]);
            
            curXList.add(curY);
        }
    }
    
    return mirroredPlanes; 
}
```

}

### Things I've tried that aren't currently in the code

- Checking to see the if laser hits a corner
- Checking to see if the laser hits the captain before the guard

### Failed Test Case

```
int[] dimensions = new int[] {42, 59};
int[] captain_position = new int [] {34, 44};
int[] badguy_position = new int[] {6, 34};
int distance = 5000;
//Desired Output: ??? (Unknown)
//Actual Output: 31694 (Incorrect)
```

Comment: What is the expected output of the test case?   What actually happens?  I see your failed test case, and your explanation of the problem is really thorough, but you didn't actually indicate what the expectation of the test or what the failure was.

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie I don't know what the expected output of the test case is. I'm technically not even supposed to know what the input for the test case is, but I was able to figure that out by brute force. When I run the test case through my code, it gives me 31694. My guess as to what the error is - is that I'm not accounting for some type of edge case which would lower that number.

Comment: How did you get the value of parallel dimension's X and Y? What's the approach you are taking to solve this. Not very clear from the solution.

Comment: @AbhilekhSingh To get the dimensions, I'm dividing the maximum laser distance by the dimensions of the room to see how many possible parallel rooms I need to check (add one to include the first room). The approach that I'm taking is to reflect the badguy's position in these parallel rooms and see if it's possible to hit that badguy (because reflecting the badguy's position is essentially unfolding the laser bounces). I'm also trying to see if the laser would hit the source before the badguy (which would be bad), but I'm not confident that I have that part correct yet.

Comment: have you finally got all test accepted?

Comment: @serhii Yes, I did finally find a solution that passed all of the test cases.

Comment: @Avix Do you mind sharing some insight on the reason of failing test case 10? I have the same problem

Comment: @Lunayo Ensure that you have a working solution for tests 1 through 9 first. Once you pass all of those tests, test 10 requires that you take some new things into consideration. What if your laser hits you (the source) before it hits the bad guy? What if your solution provides duplicate directions -> (If you think about mirroring the guard, what would happen if the laser hits a mirrored guard before it hits the mirrored guard that you are checking?)

Comment: @Avix yep I have considered and validated all these cases, but it still fails on test case 10.. :(. For the failing test cases you posted above I got the result 30895. Is it huge difference between your accepted solution?

Comment: @Lunayo I can't tell you what the answer to test case 10 is, but I can tell you that you are close. Keep checking your code for possible errors. In the end, I didn't evaluate corner points. Perhaps try removing that code?

Comment: @Avix I found the issue on my code, I missed some of the reversed sink points. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's one thing I'd like to point out here. 
In my implementation, I made divisions to calculate the unit vector. While checking if that unit vector already exists in a dictionary there was an error on the last decimal digit which made equality return false.

Comment: @Avix I was wondering if you could provide some insight on the code you've given here. I'm not sure I understand it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] dimensions = new int[] {2, 5};
int[] captain_position = new int [] {1, 2};
int[] badguy_position = new int[] {1, 4};
int distance = 11;
```

For this test your code returns 35, and my accepted (from today nonetheless) code returns 27, hope the smaller test can help you discover the bug.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Can you think of any edge cases that you accounted for that could possibly reduce the number of accepted directions? I'll be debugging on my own as well, but if you can already see a big difference, it would be helpful to know which concept I overlooked.

Comment: Update: I modified the code and was able to get it so that it passed tests 1 - 9 still, but not 10. This time I get 27 for your test case. I must still be missing something though. My incorrect answer to test case 10 is now 31135 (before it was 31694)

Comment: That may not be an answer you are looking for, but I completely changed my algorithm between a code that passed first nine tests and the accepted one. I'll try to take a look in your code when I have more time.

Comment: @MWaw I'm still trying to discover what might be different between your solution and my own. Any insight you can give on how my approach differs from yours would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RossHays The idea of cleaner algorithm is in the code, you are reflecting the point, not the laser.


Avix : Perhaps I'm not seeing it, but do you account for the laser hitting you first instead of the bad guy?

Comment: @MWaw In my most current version of the code I am trying to account for that. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, but that was the change that allowed my solution to produce 27 for your test case. It still doesn't produce the correct answer for test case 10, even though the answer it provides is different. How did you check to see if the laser hits the source first? (I've updated my code to reflect my recent work)

Comment: My first code also contained some kind of quadrants and line coefficients stuff, and probably due to float calculations not being accurate I couldn't get it to work. Hint : think about reflecting some more.

Comment: @MWaw Okay I now have it so that the source points are mirrored too, just like the target points. It's way too inefficient to check all of the source points for every target point though. How did you know which source points to check / how did you evaluate if a source point will be in the way of a target point?

Comment: Every pair (point, center) has uniquely determined line equation y = ax + b, what happens when two points have the same one?

Comment: I have the same problem, failed on Test 4 and Test 10 but passed the test posted above. May I ask for another test cases? I have tried all the corner cases.

Comment: @MWaw Hi! Could you please explain the algorithm in detail. I read the question and am not able to think of any solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Avix, how do you know your answer for a hidden test?

Answer (score 3):

Here you take some more test cases

```
dimensions = [10,10]
captain_position = [4, 4]
badguy_position = [3,3]
distance = 5000
```

I didn't use java. btw ans = 739323

```
dimensions = [23,10]
captain_position = [6, 4]
badguy_position = [3,2]
distance = 23

ans  = 8
```

I won't post code or the logic. Hint: can you see enemy behind shadow? look around yourself

Answer (score 0):

The only test I did not pass was Test 10, and I found the error to be in the part of my code that tested if a shot would hit the captain before the bad guy, so start your debugging with that area. To give you a test case, MWaw's example of

```
int[] dimensions = new int[] {2, 5};
int[] captain_position = new int [] {1, 2};
int[] badguy_position = new int[] {1, 4};
int distance = 11;
```

gave me this issue with shot angles (as vectors)

```
[-6, -3]
[-4, -5]
[-6, 5]
[-4, -7]
```