# Rectangular room with reflecting walls with a hero and enemy puzzle

Tags: python-2.6

**Current situation**

Am stuck with this Google foobar question from past 9 days with 8/10 test cases passing. Could someone please help me as to what is wrong with my code?

**Problem statement**

Uh-oh - you've been cornered by one of Commander Lambdas elite guards! Fortunately, you grabbed a beam weapon from an abandoned guardpost while you were running through the station, so you have a chance to fight your way out. But the beam weapon is potentially dangerous to you as well as to the elite guard: its beams reflect off walls, meaning you'll have to be very careful where you shoot to avoid bouncing a shot toward yourself!

Luckily, the beams can only travel a certain maximum distance before becoming too weak to cause damage. You also know that if a beam hits a corner, it will bounce back in exactly the same direction. And of course, if the beam hits either you or the guard, it will stop immediately (albeit painfully).

Write a function answer(dimensions, your_position, guard_position, distance) that gives an array of 2 integers of the width and height of the room, an array of 2 integers of your x and y coordinates in the room, an array of 2 integers of the guard's x and y coordinates in the room, and returns an integer of the number of distinct directions that you can fire to hit the elite guard, given the maximum distance that the beam can travel.

The room has integer dimensions [1 < x_dim <= 1000, 1 < y_dim <= 1000]. You and the elite guard are both positioned on the integer lattice at different distinct positions (x, y) inside the room such that [0 < x < x_dim, 0 < y < y_dim]. Finally, the maximum distance that the beam can travel before becoming harmless will be given as an integer 1 < distance <= 10000.

For example, if you and the elite guard were positioned in a room with dimensions [3, 2], you_position [1, 1], guard_position [2, 1], and a maximum shot distance of 4, you could shoot in seven different directions to hit the elite guard (given as vector bearings from your location): [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, -2], [3, 2], [3, -2], [-3, 2], and [-3, -2]. As specific examples, the shot at bearing [1, 0] is the straight line horizontal shot of distance 1, the shot at bearing [-3, -2] bounces off the left wall and then the bottom wall before hitting the elite guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(13), and the shot at bearing [1, 2] bounces off just the top wall before hitting the elite guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(5).

**Links referred**

[This post gives a test case and it is passing in my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792375/google-foobar-bringing-a-gun-to-a-guard-fight)

[This post gives a GUI to understand the problem](http://joncole.me/pages/reflector/)

**My approach**

I reflect the enemy position in the mirrored planes of the rectangular room on all directions as long as the reflected point is within the given distance from the source point. This will give the enemy positions in reflected planes as a straight line from source. This distance is less than the given distance. Once these points are generated, I check if any of the points from that list makes the beam passes through hero before hitting the enemy.

**Code in Python**

```
from math import *

BOTTOM_LEFT = (0,0)
TOP_RIGHT   = (0,0)
SOURCE      = (0,0)
TARGET      = (0,0)
DISTANCE    = 0
BOTTOM_RIGHT    = (0,0)
TOP_LEFT    = (0,0)

def answer(tr, src, bp, dist):
    global BOTTOM_LEFT
    BOTTOM_LEFT = (0,0)
    global TOP_RIGHT
    TOP_RIGHT = tr
    global SOURCE
    SOURCE = src
    global TARGET
    TARGET = bp
    global DISTANCE
    DISTANCE = dist
    global BOTTOM_RIGHT
    BOTTOM_RIGHT = (TOP_RIGHT[0], BOTTOM_LEFT[1])
    global TOP_LEFT
    TOP_LEFT = (BOTTOM_LEFT[0], TOP_RIGHT[1])
    all_targets = get_targets(start_point = TARGET, distance = DISTANCE)
    CORNERS = [BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT, TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT]
    corner_angles = [4]
    i = 0
    while i < 4:
        ca = degrees(atan2(CORNERS[i][1] - SOURCE[1], CORNERS[i][0] - SOURCE[0]))
        corner_angles.append(ca)
        i = i+1
    valid_angles = set()
    for tgt in all_targets:
        pa = degrees(atan2(tgt[1] - SOURCE[1], tgt[0] - SOURCE[0]))
        if(tgt[0] - SOURCE[0] > 0 ):
            valid_angles.add(pa)
        elif(tgt[0] - SOURCE[0] < 0):
            if pa % 45 != 0 and pa not in corner_angles:
                valid_angles.add(pa)
        else:
            valid_angles.add(pa)
    if(src == bp):
        return 0
    else:
        return len(valid_angles)

def get_mirrored(point):
    ret = []
    x = point[0]
    y = point[1] - 2*(point[1] - TOP_RIGHT[1])
    ret.append((x,y))
    ret.append((point[0], point[1] - 2*(point[1] - BOTTOM_LEFT[1])))
    ret.append((point[0] - 2*(point[0] - BOTTOM_LEFT[0]), point[1]))
    ret.append((point[0] - 2*(point[0] - TOP_RIGHT[0]), point[1]))
    return ret

def get_targets(start_point, distance):
    targets = []
    targets.append(start_point)
    all_targets = set()
    all_targets.add((start_point[0],start_point[1]))
    last_targets = all_targets
    while True:
        new_level_targets = set()
        for tgt in last_targets:
            new_targets = get_mirrored(tgt)
            new_targets = set(t for t in new_targets if hypot(SOURCE[0] - t[0], SOURCE[1] - t[1]) <= DISTANCE)
            new_targets -= all_targets
            new_level_targets |= new_targets
        if not new_level_targets:
            break
        all_targets |= new_level_targets
        last_targets = new_level_targets
    return all_targets

print(answer((3,2), (1,1), (2,1), 4)) #Answer 7
print(answer((300,275), (150,150), (185,100), 500) #Answer 9
```